# Low Top Tube Xtracycle Donor Frame?

Tags: cargo, geometry

One of my most useful bicycles is my 58cm 700c Xtracycle based on a Novara Xpresso cyclocross style frame. Lately, as the kids are getting bigger and my back isn't getting any younger: I crave a much lower top bar. I would consider a used mixte frame, a step-through frame, or other really low diamond frame. Recommendations for sturdy and faithful frame models appreciated. Ability to handle 3 rings and 8 cogs plus a chain stay bridge preferred.

These areas would help me evaluate the frames I might find:

- **Stability:** I have heard some people mutter that mixte frames are "unstable" as donor frames. Is this substantial? (I get some shimmy and flex in my present Xtracycle but I'm running a cro-moly frame but it doesn't bother me.)
- **Fit:** Is there a more limited range of geometry among these frames? Could I find frames like these around 56-58cm or about 19.5 inches? If it is a large "WSD" style frame, how much difference does that make for a male pilot?
- **Strength:** Are frames with lower top bars any weaker?  Steel is not a requirement, but I expect to load it up with camping gear and elementary school
  age kids.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the second hand market for 'Giant Trail' mountain bikes from a few years ago.  These had an unusual frame design with a lower top tube, wider, more stable bars and disc brakes. Giant Rincon Trail, Giant Boulder Trail were a couple of the affordable models I remember.

[image]

Comment: That's not an "unusual frame design".  Other than the little curve between top tube and seat tube it's a standard [mixte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step-through_frame#Mixte) frame.  The frame is quite strong, and in fact has a reputation for being stiffer than a diamond frame -- almost too stiff.  Was a popular BSO youth "mountain bike" frame for a couple of decades before the fancy suspended frames took over that market.

Comment: Trek makes a few bikes with this style frame, one such model is the Neko (http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/town/dual_sport/neko/neko/#)

Comment: I like this frame design, and I like the Neko's frame design. They make me think that should look at early 29er frames because I don't need disk. However the market on hardtail 29er frames seems pretty slim.